# Win XP console application: API to change width, change height

Tags: winapi, console-application

Win32 console application (printf, fgets, etc)
opens famous 25x80  "black box".

I want my application to programmatically set
different width and height, other than 25x80.

Which APIs can I use to resize my console windows ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the record, I achievd what I needed using weird line

```
system("mode 42,90");
```

So weird, but simple, and it worked.

Comment: -1, Does not answer the question, the question specifically asks for an API to change the size of a console window. 'Mode' is a command shell command.

Answer (score 3):

Sets the console size to 210*50 and the buffer to 210*2000

```
COORD s = { 210, 2000 };
SMALL_RECT sr = { 0, 0, 209, 49 };
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbi = { 0 };
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &sbi);
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), s);
if ( (sbi.srWindow.Right - sbi.srWindow.Left) != (sr.Right - sr.Left) ) {
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), TRUE, &sr);
}
```

Comment: That means the SetConsoleWindowInfo call failed, likely because the window couldn't fit on your monitor. Try reducing it to e.g. 100x40.